# Problem with mY SQL output using IBMCLOUD

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-cloud

I'm using ibm.cloud db2 console
My question is I think my script is ok but why there is no output?

````
CREATE TABLE employee( empNo VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 lastName VARCHAR(15),
 firstName VARCHAR(15),
 gender CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT gender_ck CHECK(gender in ('M','F')));
 
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('DESCRIBE TABLE employee'); 

CREATE SEQUENCE empNo_seq
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 2 
NO CYCLE  
CACHE 5;

INSERT INTO employee
VALUES (LPAD(NEXT VALUE FOR empNo_seq, 5, '0'), 'Smith', 'John', 'M');

SELECT * FROM employee;```
````

Comment: Your code basically works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=302b0597f027c9b27c8efbffb61f38f7.

Comment: Maybe you need to run a `COMMIT` after the `INSERT` and before the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the script shown above in my environment with my Db2 on cloud instance. To verify that table "employee" is created and record was inserted into it, open Console, choose EXPLORE - Tables in the menu, click on your schema, click table name on the right and click  below - you will see the data is there. At the same time, there is a problem with "select * from anytable" in some browsers - it runs with no errors reported but no results are displayed, for example, in Windows 10 this happens for Google Chrome Version Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)
and for Microsoft Edge Version 87.0.664.66 (Official build) (64-bit) and for Opera Version 73.0.3856.284. There is no problem with previous versions, for example on Knoppix 8.5 it works well with Chromium Version 72.0.3626.53, Konqueror Version 5.0.97
and Firefox Quantum, Extended Support Release, 60.5.0esr.

Firefox 84.0 does not have the problem neither on Window 10/8.1 nor on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

So, if we want to use Console as a Db2 client, we have to use Firefox - unless someone else knows how to fix problem with Chrome or Edge browsers.
Or we have to use different db client - for example, db2cli or clpplus, which are working from command line.

Good luck!